# Hibernate ConcurrentModificationException problem in Stress testing

Tags: java, hibernate, java.util.concurrent

There is an application with the following configuration:

1- HK2 for DI

2- Hibernate for ORM

and

3- GrizzlyHttpServer

and the its hibernate configuration is :

```
import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.boot.*;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.jvnet.hk2.annotations.Service;

@Service
public class HibernateOracle {
    private Session session;
    private SessionFactory factory;

    public HibernateOracle() {
        final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure() // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml
                .build();
        factory = new MetadataSources(registry).addPackage("com.art.entity").buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
        session = factory.openSession();
    }

    public Session getSession() {
        if (session == null || !session.isOpen())
            session = factory.openSession();
        return this.session;
    }


}
```

and the one method of a repository file is:

```
@jakarta.inject.Inject
private HibernateOracle hibernateOracle;

@Override
    public User get(String username) throws UserNotFoundException {
        Session session = hibernateOracle.getSession();
        try {
            return (User) session.createNamedQuery("User.findOneByUserName")
                    .setParameter("username", username).getSingleResult();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new UserNotFoundException();
        } finally {
            //
        }
    }
```

It is worked correctly in the normal state but when the application is tested by such as load-test the following exception is raised in this method:

> java.util.ConcurrentModificationException     at
> java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1424)    at
> org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl.releaseResources(ResourceRegistryStandardImpl.java:328)
> at
> org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.afterTransaction(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:60)
> at
> org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.afterTransaction(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:167)
> at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.afterTransaction(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:276)
> at
> org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.afterOperation(SessionImpl.java:550)
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1464)   at
> org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1649)
> at
> org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617)
> at
> org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1665)
> at
> com.art.vesal.backend.core.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl.get(UserDaoImpl.java:238)
> at
> com.art.vesal.backend.core.controller.customer_management.UserControllerImpl.get(UserControllerImpl.java:159)
> at
> com.art.vesal.backend.core.controller.customer_management.CustomerControllerImpl.checkCustomer(CustomerControllerImpl.java:598)
> at
> com.art.vesal.backend.core.controller.messaging.MTSMSControllerImpl.sendMessageManyToMany(MTSMSControllerImpl.java:282)
> at
> com.art.vesal.backend.core.controller.messaging.ArtMTSMSImpl.sendMessageManyToMany(ArtMTSMSImpl.java:140)
> at
> com.art.vesal.backend.core.controller.rest.MessageRelayRest.sendMessageManyToMany(MessageRelayRest.java:26)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor35.invoke(Unknown
> Source)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:124)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:167)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:219)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:475)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:397)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:81)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:255)
> at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)  at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:234)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
> at
> org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:356)
> at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:190)
> at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:535)
> at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:515)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Where is the problem and how do I fix it such hibernate connection polling and so on?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the `@Service` annotation does, but I'm guessing it defines a singleton, and so you're sharing a single `Session` between all concurrent threads.

That's illegal, of course.

Comment: What is your suggestion? The session is created per request?

Comment: That, or per transaction. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_transactional_patterns_and_anti_patterns